# Workflows return unpredictable results on long workflow calls in foreach parallels

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

When I call a workflow in another workflow's foreach -parallel, I get weird and inconsistent results. Here's some sample code:

```
workflow test-workflow1 {
    Start-Sleep 2
    "Stuff"
}

workflow test-workflow2 {
    foreach -parallel ($thing in @(1, 2, 4, 4)) {
        $rezult = test-workflow1
        InlineScript {
            write-host $($USING:rezult)
        }
    }
}

test-workflow2
```

What will happen is that it will print out `Stuff` at differing intervals, with blank lines in between. Sometimes it won't even print `Stuff` at all. Here are some examples:

```
Stuff
Stuff Stuff Stuff
```

Another:

```
Stuff


Stuff
Stuff Stuff
```

I can guess that there's something going on with the threading, and that in being a long running workflow it is somehow being asynchronous and returning some PSDataCollection to $rezult, but I don't understand why it's not being synchronous. There are other weird things like if I return an object I get an array back with all of my elements crammed into one element and then a bunch of empty elements. I use the above as an example, but really this is hitting me hardest when I use Invoke-RestMethod because sometimes it returns fast and everything is fine, but other times it's slow and produces this weird behavior. Also, when -throttlelimit on the foreach is set to 1 it works perfectly fine, albeit slow.

Can anyone explain what's going on here or how to fix it?

Comment: Workflows as I understand, comes with a lot of restrictions, deserialized output being one of them. That explains part of your problem. Here is a good read: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions/. Nevertheless, if I need to multi thread, I prefer `Runspaces`. Sometimes I use jobs if I need to spin up something quickly.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean "deserialized output"? What part of the example isn't deserialized?

Comment: Meaning, its not supposed to be synchronous. Output is displayed as soon as the thread finishes executing regardless of the order in which it was invoked.

Comment: Workflows aren't functions, they're not code executed top to bottom; that's what `inlinescript` is for, to include that kind of code in a workflow.